# Clock not publishing?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, jackal, stereo, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm launching a bumblebee2 stereo camera to get my input images. When I check the /clock topic, I don't see any timestamps being published. Is this abnormal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299184/clock-not-publishing?/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, [it's not abnormal](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock). The `/clock` topic is only used if you are not using the wall clock. For example, if you are using a simulation then the `/clock` topic is published to provide the simulated world time, because it is often different from the real world time. This allows nodes to execute at the same pace as the simulation.

When using hardware distributed on the network, and not using not simulation or log files (i.e. when `/clock` is empty), to make sure everything in your system uses the same time you must use a tool such as NTP to keep all system clocks synced.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3